# InvalidBucketName with Java AWS SDK 1.x using S3 Access points

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java, amazon-s3-access-points

I am trying to perform `GetObject` operation on a bucket via configured `accesspoint` through AWS SDK version 1.x (tried with 1.12.348 and 1.11.1004):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
  <version>1.12.348</version>
</dependency>
```

I have following code to execute the `GetObject` operation:

```
AmazonS3 amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(awsRegion).build();

String bucketName= "arn:aws:s3:<bucket-region>:<accountNumber>:accesspoint:<access-point-name>";
String key = "bucket/path/filename.txt";
File to = // a file;

amazonS3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key), to);
```

According to the documentation bucketName can be:

> The name of the bucket, or access point ARN, containing the desired object.

And..

> When using this operation using an access point through the Amazon Web Services SDKs, you provide the access point ARN in place of the bucket name. For more information about access point ARNs, see Using access points in the Amazon Simple Storage Service Developer Guide.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html

However this is throwing an error:

```
<Error><Code>InvalidBucketName</Code><Message>The specified bucket is not valid.</Message><BucketName>arn:aws:s3:<bucket-region>:<accountNumber>:accesspoint:<access-point-name></BucketName><RequestId>**********</RequestId><HostId>*******************</HostId></Error>
```

With the error it looks like it doesn't support the ARN formatted bucket name and complaining about special characters within the ARN accesspoint name.

PS: Within accesspoint value `arn:aws:s3:<bucket-region>:<accountNumber>:accesspoint:<access-point-name>`, actual values are replaces with placeholders between <>, so the error won't be related to these characters. This are presented here with placeholders for data protection purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pom.xml` has another transitive dependency `com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:jar:1.11.375:compile` coming from following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
  <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

`aws-java-sdk-bundle` was overriding most of the classes from the original `aws-java-sdk-s3`.

Swapping the position with `hadoop-aws` and `aws-java-sdk-s3` resolved the issue! (pushing dependency `aws-java-sdk-s3` before `hadoop-aws`)